# If you already have a condition or there are none left in the deck, can you gain an effect--that normally induces a condition--for free?

Tags: eldritch-horror

I believe if all the cards of a certain kind are gone from the deck and you are told to take that condition, you simply gain the benefit of not having to take the condition.  What if you are offered the option to take a condition in exchange for some side effect and either you already have the condition or it is not present in the deck?

I would think you would not be able to gain the side effect because the wording "you may gain a **_ condition to _**" does not get fulfilled as you didn't **gain** the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I believe you are correct - you cannot.**  A similar but more common situation that can occur in the game is when you are given the option to become delayed in order to gain a benefit.  "Delayed" does not have a card to represent it, so one cannot run out of them, and in these cases, the benefit only occurs if you do in fact become delayed - you cannot prevent it (such as with the *Pocketwatch*) and still gain the benefit.  It would stand to reason that other effects that use the phrasing of "you may x to y" follow the same rules.

Comment: It makes it seem like Mark Harrigan's "cannot be delayed unless you choose to" ability doesn't pack much punch to it. I guess it fits along the lines of the story that he's tough enough to not be manhandled into being delayed, but it doesn't make him superhuman and able to complete tasks that typically require some delay.

Comment: @Joey Precisely so.